# Error in Exception handling in Python script

Tags: python, exception, python-3.x

```
    m = ldap.initialize(server)
    try:
        m.start_tls_s()
    except ldap.LDAPError, e:
        print e
```

This part of a python script. I am getting the error in the line "except ldap.LDAPError, e:". But it seems to be right. Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: And what version of Python are you using?

Comment: i am using Python 3. It says "Invalid Syntax"

Comment: @Andy please edit your question and include critical information like python version, os, significant portion of the code or more details about it's behaviour, as well as the error you're getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use Python 3 that's

```
m = ldap.initialize(server)
try:
    m.start_tls_s()
except ldap.LDAPError as e:
    print(e)
```

See the [language reference](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/compound_stmts.html#except).